# how to find the most frequent in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm a newbie in python, and I need to find the most frequent element in list `pdInput` and how many elements are the same in the list of `mostFreqenNum`

```py
    mostFreqenNum = []
    contMostnum = [0]
    
    ContTraining = int(input('How many time You like to Train you input: '))
        for i in range(ContTraining):
            pdInput = int(
                input('Please input your number whatever you want: '))
            mostFreqenNum.append(pdInput)
            for x in mostFreqenNum:
                coutFreqenNum = contMostnum.count(x)
```

Comment: Sort the list then check consequetive integers in list, if found you can make a dictionary mapping and update it accordingly, you will need two seperate dictionary, one to record frequency and other to match duplicates.

Comment: `pdInput` doesn't seem to be a list in your code.

Comment: @MarkMeyer sorry about that, I was confused about this case for 2 days. all I mean is list 'mostFreqenNum'

Answer (score 8):

given a list of values `inp`, you can find the most common like this:

1. using `collections.Counter`

   `from collections import Counter`

   `most_common = Counter(inp).most_common(1)`

output is a `tuple` with `(value, count)` inside

2. using `sorted`

   `sorted(inp, key=lambda x: inp.count(x), reverse=True)[0]`

output is the most common value in the list

3. using `numpy`: `# note only works with numeric values`

   `np.argmax(np.bincount(inp))`

output is the most common value in the list

4. one more using `builtins`:

   `max(set(inp), key=inp.count)`

output is the most common value in the list

5. another using `pandas`:

   `import pandas as pd`

   `pd.value_counts(inp).index[0]`

output is the most common value in the list

Answer (score 3):

Why you dont use the built in module from python, statistics.
you can use the module like these :

```py
import statistics
### your input code
mode = statistics.mode(mostFreqenNum)
print(mode)
```

mode() receive parameter list type.
Then you can use the count().
Another example, maybe like these:

```py
>>> import statistics
>>> lists = [2,3,2,2,3,4,5]
>>> mode = statistics.mode(lists)
>>> print(mode)
2
>>> lists.count(2)
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but maybe this could work:

```
mostFreqenNum = {}
contMostnum = 0
myList = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3]

for i in myList:
    if i in mostFreqenNum:
        mostFreqenNum[i] += 1
    else:
        mostFreqenNum[i] = 1
        
for x in mostFreqenNum:
    if mostFreqenNum[x] > contMostnum:
        contMostnum = mostFreqenNum[x]
        mostFreqKey = x
    else:
        continue

print(f'Most frequent key, {mostFreqKey}, seen {contMostnum} times.')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def Prediction_Model_v3():
alnv3 = [[],[]]
inpv3 = int(input('How many time You like to Train you input V3: '))
for i in range(inpv3):
    pdInpv3 = int(
        input('V3 input number whatever you want: '))
    alnv3[0].append(pdInpv3)
    mdv3 = statistics.mode(alnv3[0])
    if(pdInpv3 == mdv3):
        alnv3[1].append(str(len(alnv3[1])))
    print('numberInput V3: ', alnv3[0])
print('Most Frequent number V3 is ', str(mdv3), ':', str(len(alnv3[1])))
pdtISv3 = (((inpv3-int(len(alnv3[1])))*100)/inpv3)
print('Result of prediction V3 is: ', str(
    mdv3), '=', str(pdtISv3), '%')
alnv3.clear()
return str(pdtISv3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
from typing import Counter
numbers = [1,3,7,4,3,0,3,6,3]
c = Counter(numbers).most_common()
print(f"The most frequent number  {c[0][0]} was {c[0][1]} times repeated")
```

Comment: A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. It is a collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values.

Comment: most_commen() ; return a list of the  most common elements and their counts from the most common to the least.

Comment: You can edit your answer instead of adding the comments.